# Updating record not working in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql

I have this sequence generation query that gets the current sequence and increment it to next value. But the increment is not updating. The nextval is always returning 1, the default value from the database

```
Entity  | StartVal | Increment | CurVal | NextVal
----------------------------------------------------
INVOICE |   0      |     1     |   0    |   1
```

The nextval should be 3, 5, 7 and so on

```
int nextVal = 0;
using (var db = new MedicStoreDataContext())
{
    DAL.LINQ.Sequence seq = (from sq in db.Sequences
                where sq.Entity == entity
                select sq).SingleOrDefault();

    if (seq != null)
    {
        nextVal = seq.NextVal.HasValue ? seq.NextVal.Value : 0;


        seq.NextVal = nextVal + 2;

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

}
```

Have I left something undone?

**UPDATE:**
Answer: I needed to set the Primary Key and update Sequence class field to include the Primary Key

Comment: I am using Sql CE and I don't want to go through the hassle - like it doesn't support multiple statements.

Comment: You need to add a primary key to the table for this to work, and also update the linq 2 sql class.

Comment: are you sure the `seq` is not null. step-through the code and you will know the LINQ query might not correct ?

Comment: I have stepped through the code several times, the computation is right

Comment: I didn't have my PK set on the entity column. I just did that. I also need to update the class and see how it goes

Comment: @tcoder which was my reply to you - please then mark my answer as correct

Comment: @BugFinder - Improve your answer. It's not completely clear. Just for the sake of other visitors. Also include PK reference and I will mark it as answer

Comment: @tcoder done.. a lot of the doucmentation I found on linq to sql referred to it as a unique identifier.. which is also another name for it..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this is because it hasnt found the unique identifier (or Primary Key) for a table.

In your data descriptions are you sure the table correctly picked up the unique item? - when I first tried this although I had a unique key etc, the table description in c# didnt mark it as unique, so the linq quietly didnt updated it as I had expected, no errors no warnings. Once I corrected the data table in c#, it all went well.

Comment: Thanks. I actually didn't have my PK set on the entity column. I just did that. I also needed to update the LINQ generated class to reflect the PK changes and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Isn't that the correct behaviour? wouldn't you expect nextVal to be 1 if CurVal is 0? I may be missing something here but it seems like your overcomplicating it a bit. Isn't what you want to do basically

```
using (var db = new MedicStoreDataContext())
{
    DAL.LINQ.Sequence seq = (from sq in db.Sequences
                where sq.Entity == entity
                select sq).SingleOrDefault();

    if (seq != null)
    {
        seq.CurVal += seq.Increment;

        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

I don't see why you need the whole nextVal bit at all. Please feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Also to note, your not incrementing CurVal and also you're not updating/inserting the class (I'm assuming the sample was cut down on purpose)

Comment: Again, not sure if your nextval is a computed column of curval + 1. If it is your issue is just that your not updating CurVal

Comment: I didn't have my PK set on the entity column. I just did that. I also need to update the class and see how it goes

Comment: :@Manatherin: thanks. It was the PK that was absent. I had a wrong thought that I was working on an instance and it should update itself.